# Unknown language in SPSS syntax window

Tags: spss

I am using SPSS 20 and facing a strange problem in my syntax window. My locale and everything is set to English. The OS keyboard is Deutsch. However, whenever I am typing something in the syntax window it converts to another language unknown to me. If I copy paste those unknown language codes into a text editor, then it shows in English! Is there anyone who can assist me to solve the problem?

Screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgyEP.png).

[image: Syntax window vs. text editor window]

Comment: On a side note, the compute filter statement could be better written as: COMPUTE filter_$=ANY(Country, 4, 8, 10, 14, 26, 28, 32, 33, 37). I would check to ensure you have the latest FIX PACKS installed, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Jignesh Sutar, that is indeed a nice tip to write compute statement. My one is a way bit nasty.
I have the fix pack 2 installed.

Comment: I would log with SPSS Technical Support, they are generally quite good at investigating these types of things.